# If $x^3+y^3=72$ and $xy=8$ then find the value of $x-y$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, problem-solving

I recently came across a question,

> If $x^3+y^3=72$ and $xy=8$ then find the value of $(x-y)$.

By trial and error I found that $x=4$ and $y=2$ satisfies both the conditions. But in general how can I solve it analytically? I tried using $a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2+b^2-ab)$ and also $a^3+b^3=(a+b)^3-3ab(a+b)$. But both ways aren't working.

Please explain how do I solve these types of questions analytically.

Comment: "Find the value of $x-y$" seems to imply that the solution is unique, but obviously $x = 2$ and $y=4$ is also a solution, ie. there is no clear answer to the original question.

Comment: This question was asked in SSC-CGL-2015 on 9 Aug 2015. Their statement was $x^3+y^3=72$ and $xy=6$ and options were $0,2,-2,4,$ out of which only one could be selected.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hint: 
$$x^3+y^3=72\text{ and }x^3y^3=512.$$

You know the sum, and you know the product of two cubes.

> The cubes are $\dfrac{72\pm\sqrt{72^2-4\cdot 512}}2$, $8$ and $64$.

Answer (score 7):

Given  $$x^3+y^3=72$$
$$xy=8$$
Notice,

$$(x+y)^3=x^3+y^3+3xy(x+y)$$ $$(x+y)^3=72+3(8)(x+y)$$
$$(x+y)^3-24(x+y)-72=0$$

Above is the cubic equation in terms of $(x+y)$ which has one real root $6$ Hence, we get $$x+y=6$$

Now, $$(x-y)^2=(x+y)^2-4xy$$
$$(x-y)=\pm\sqrt{(x+y)^2-4xy}$$

$$x-y=\pm\sqrt{(6)^2-4\times8 }$$
$$=\pm\sqrt{4}=\pm 2$$
Hence, we have 
$$\bbox[5px, border:2px solid #C0A000]{\color{red}{x-y=\pm 2}}$$

Comment: This is a really neat way to do it! +1

Comment: How did you solve that cubic equation?

Comment: hit & trial by taking  only positive values as  1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6                                      You may also solve it at Wolfram.alpha

Comment: @HarishChandraRajpoot But in general if the answer could be 3/2 etc then  how would we solve, because in another question $x^3+y^3=72$ and $xy=6$ is given. No not at wolfram, I want to know how to solve it by hand.

Answer (score 4):

You may solve this by brute force. Write $x=8/y$. The first equation now reads

$x^3+\frac{512}{x^3}=72$.

Multiply both sides by $x^3$, and you have

$x^6+512-72x^3=0$.

Define $u\equiv x^3$, and the equation becomes

$u^2-72u+512=0$.

Use the quadratic formula to solve for $u$, solve back for x, and solve for y.

Answer (score 4):

It's two equations, with two variables. We can do what we always do. You can write $y= 8/x$, and substitute into the first equation, obtaining $x^3 + 8^3/x^3 =72.$

From here, we want to write this as a polynomial, so we multiply through $x^3$ so there are no negative powers, and then move everything to the left. This gives $x^6-72x^3+512.$ This is a pretty large polynomial, but since all the exponents are multiples of 3, all is not lost. We'll set $u=x^3$ and obtain $u^2-72u + 512$. The quadratic formula gives the factorization $(u-8)(u-64)=0,$ which of course implies that $u=8$ or that $u=64$.

Now we just go through the substitution in $u$. We write $x^3 = 8$ or $x^3 = 64$. There is only one cube root when dealing with real numbers, so we have $x=2$ or $x=4$. If $x=2$, then we have $y=8/2=4$. If $x=4$, then we have $y=8/4=2$.

So there are two solutions then, depending on the case. Either $x-y = 2$ or $x-y=-2$ depending on which pair of solutions you work with.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the basic shapes of the curves $xy=c$ (a hyperbola centered at the origin with diagonal axes) and $x^3+y^3=c$ (for $c$ positive, something like a bell curve tilted clockwise 45 degrees) then it's clear there can be exactly two solutions, exactly one solution, or no solutions. It's not so crazy to stumble upon $(2,4)$ and $(4,2)$ as solutions, and then the visual confirms there can be no more.

If you wanted to be more formal with this approach, you could establish that

- only in the first quadrant are both curves present
- in the first quadrant, both curves are decreasing as $x$ increases
- in the first quadrant, one curve is concave down while the other is concave up

This is enough to establish that there could be only $0$, $1$, or $2$ solutions. Since $(2,4)$ and $(4,2)$ fit the bill, you're done.